# Randomly select x number of items from class list in python

Tags: python, list, class, random, jython

In jython, I have a class of objects defined like this:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, pid, aisle, bay, hits, qtyPerOrder):
    self.pid = pid
    self.aisle = int(aisle)
    self.bay = bay
    self.hits = int(hits)
    self.qtyPerOrder = int(qtyPerOrder)
```

I have created a class list called "list" of the items in the class with 4000~ lines that look like this:

```
'PO78141', 13, ' B ', 40
```

I'm trying to randomly select a number within the range of 3 and 20 called x. Then, the code will select x number of lines in the list.

For example: if x = 5 I want it to return:

```
'PO78141', 13, ' B ', 40
'MA14338', 13, ' B ', 40
'GO05143', 13, ' C ', 40
'SE162004', 13, ' F ', 40
'WA15001', 13, ' F ', 40
```

**EDIT**
Ok, that seems to work. However, it is returning this <**main**.Item object at 0x029990D0>. how do i get it to return it in the format above?

Comment: Don't name anything `list` in python, as that'd shadow the built-in type.

Comment: To select N random elements from a list use `random.sample`: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`random` module](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/random.html) to both pick a number between 3 and 20, and to take a sample of lines:

```
import random

sample_size = random.randint(3, 20)
sample = random.sample(yourlist, sample_size)

for item in sample:
    print '%s, %d, %s, %d' % (item.pid, item.aisle, item.bay, item.hits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remark - I renamed the list to `lst`. Assuming that you have a list of objects, try the following:

```
from random import randint
for item in lst[:randint(3, 20)]:
    (item.pid, item.aisle, item.bay, item.hits)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying "I want it to return"?

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0
while i < randint(3, 20):
    # Display code here.
    i += 1
```

Comment: `randint` is not a sequence. `for i in randint(3, 20)` fails with a `TypeError`.

Comment: now you'll test `i` against a new random value *every time you loop*. It'll end up fine, but you'd be better off with `for i in xrange(randint(3, 20)):`